# Ghostscript call in C# assembly cannot be found

Tags: c#, ghostscript

I am using a GhostScript assembly in to convert PDF files to images.
The method I used is like this: 
http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/GhostScriptUseWithCSharp.aspx

When I am using the code that is provided on my workstation in a web project (Windows 7 x64) everything works perfect.

However when Deploying this to a server (Windows server 2008 R2 x64) a get an error like this.

> System.DllNotFoundException: Unable to load DLL 'gsdll32.dll': The specified module could not be found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007007E)

I did put the ghostscript assembly in the bin folder of my web application and did change the setting for the iis application pool to allow 32 bit applications.

How can it be that it doesn't work on a Server 2008 R2 environment, when both environments are 64 bit?

Comment: I had the same problem, and I eventually found that only the GhostScriptSharp.dll was in the web application bin folder, and not the gsdll32.dl - both are needed.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that your project itself is x86...

Comment: I did try to change the project to x86, but it had the exact same error.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried downloading x64 version of ghostscript (gs863w64.exe, GPL Ghostscript 8.63 for 64-bit Windows (x86_64).) and compiling code into x64 ?

Comment: Did you mean this to be a comment? Asking a new question doesn't really count as an answer...

Comment: yes but is seams I have only comment for the last Answer, and I didn't want to comment last Answer. And in same time my question is the answer, what I have asked is what I am using on my laptop. 

Also web sites on IIS on x64 OS's by default requires x64 DLL's. Unless if you set Web Sites Pool to be 32-bit, but notice changing this to the 32-bit will render all web sites using this pool to 32-bit so you will have to compile to 32-bit. Also Installation Custom Action projects must be set to All CPU ;) ...